# Using Jquery to verify with database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am pretty new to `jquery` but I was wondering if they is a way to run `mysql` with with my jquery below.

In my `cart.php` I have a `query` with check if whatever is getting posted is in the database and if not it, the item will not be added.

In my view.php page which is where the below `jquery` and `hidden div` is in. which `works` when you click on the `add button` the hidden div shows you what you have added.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="show_hide" id="button" name="submit">Add</button>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selected').hide();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var length = $('#length option:selected').text();
        var Category = $('#Category').val();
        var cat = $('#Category option:selected').text();
        var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var qty = parseInt($('#Qty').val());
        var price =  parseFloat($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * qty;
        price = '\u00A3' + price.toFixed(2);
        var category = $('#Category').val();
        if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Quantity should not be below 1 or null');
            return false; // don't continue
        }
        else {
        $('#sprice').text(price);
        $('#scategory').text(cat);
        $('#slength').text(length);
        $('#selected').slideDown();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '../cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { pid:pid, 
            length:length, 
            Qty:Qty, 
            Category:Category },
            success: function(data)
            {
             location.reload();  
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

**Hidden div**

```
<div id="selected">
    <table class="tableclass">
            <tr>
                <td>Price:</td>
                <td id='sprice'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Category:</td>
                <td id='scategory'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Length:</td>
                <td id='slength'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Edited** *To add Query code*

In the cart.php page I have this `query`

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Category ct, Itemised ip, Product pd
                         WHERE ct.CatID = ? AND ip.Length = ? AND pd.pid = ?
                         ");
     $statement->execute(array($Category, $length, $pid));
     if (!$statement->fetch()) {
         exit();
     }
```

which i use to check that the posted content exist in the database. This is more or less the same query which I want to run in the jquery to check if the `var` exist and if not the `url:./cart.php` shouldnot run.

**Updated to show my cart.php code**

```
if(isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['length']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['Category'])){   
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
    $Category = $_POST['Category'];;
    $wasFound = false;

     dbconnect();
     $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Category ct, Itemised_Product ip, Product pd
                         WHERE ct.CatID = ? AND ip.ItemID = ? AND pd.Sef = ?
                         ");
     $statement->execute(array($Category, $length, $pid));
     if (!$statement->fetch()) {
         exit();
     }

     $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $array_key=>$each_item) { 
              if ($each_item['item_id'] == $pid  && $each_item['length'] == $length && $each_item['Category'] == $Category) {
                      $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$qty;
                      $wasFound = true;

                  } 
              } 
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));

           }
    }
    header('Location: '.fetchinline($bpages).$currentFile);
    exit();
}
```

**My question**
In the cart page I have that query which checks that the posted content haven't been check by the user. I want to do the same with my jquery above and if the user `have` I want to stop I want to stop the `hidden div` from showing.

I hope I have explain it to your understand. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand fully your question. Is it:

1. Press the Add button
2. AJAX request to check if product exist
3. If yes then show hidden div?

OR

1. Press the Add button
2. Reveal hidden field with more info
3. Add product to the cart

Anyway, in both of the above you can do AJAX request to the server and check if the product exist. If you look into $.ajax success function then the 'data' is actually response from the server and you can include anything you need and process the data with javascript/jquery.

Comment: the first one. also I have already use `url` in my query. as u can see

Comment: that url, add item cart but before i run that `url` i want to run another `url` which check does the check and if the check is valid then the rest of the jquery runs and if not, the rest of the jquery dont run.

Comment: I would get rid of the location.reload() inside AJAX and process the response from the server there and if the response is giving me OK to show the div then you could do $('#selected').slideDown();

I like to use one request at a time so it's keeping it simpler and not overloading unnecessarily servers.

Comment: `location.reload()` reload the page to show the number of item in the cart.

Comment: Are you in a cart or product page?

Comment: the `Jquery` runs on the product page.

Comment: I have updated my question to show my `query` in the `cart.php` to check if the post content exist in the database

Comment: From what I can see the hidden div it's not a form and it should show after the product has been added to the cart so I would still recommend to use only one AJAX request but modify cart.php and send appropriate response back.

1. Add product
2. In cart.php check if product exist
3. If exist add to the cart and return status=success
4. If doesn't exist return status=no product found
5. If anything else went wrong return status=error
6. In javascript you can do a condition for each status and action it

Answer (score 0):

Js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selected').hide();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var length = $('#length option:selected').text();
        var Category = $('#Category').val();
        var cat = $('#Category option:selected').text();
        var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var qty = parseInt($('#Qty').val());
        var price =  parseFloat($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * qty;
        price = '\u00A3' + price.toFixed(2);
        var category = $('#Category').val();
        if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Quantity should not be below 1 or null');
            return false; // don't continue
        }
        else {
        $('#sprice').text(price);
        $('#scategory').text(cat);
        $('#slength').text(length);
        $('#selected').slideDown();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '../cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { pid:pid, 
            length:length, 
            Qty:Qty, 
            Category:Category },
            dataType:json,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.response=='failed')
                {
                    alert('error');
                }
                else if(data.response=='success')
                {
                    alert('success');
                    //location.reload();  
                }
                else if(data.response == 'already_in_database') 
                {
                    alert('Already exists in database');
                }   
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Cart.php

```
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['length']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['Category']))
{
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
    $Category = $_POST['Category'];
    $wasFound = false;

    dbconnect();
    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Category ct, Itemised_Product ip, Product pd
                         WHERE ct.CatID = ? AND ip.ItemID = ? AND pd.Sef = ?
                         ");
    $statement->execute(array($Category, $length, $pid));
    $result=array();
    if (!$statement->fetch())
    {
        $result['response'] = 'already_in_database';
        echo jsone_encode($result);
        die();
    }

    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)
    {
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
    }
    else
    {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"]as $array_key => $each_item)
        {
            if ($each_item['item_id'] == $pid && $each_item['length'] == $length && $each_item['Category'] == $Category)
            {
                $_SESSION["cart_array"][$array_key]['quantity']+=$qty;
                $wasFound = true;
            }
        }
        if ($wasFound == false)
        {
            array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "length" => $length, "Category" => $Category, "quantity" => $qty));
        }
    }
    header('Location: ' . fetchinline($bpages) . $currentFile);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: i added your answer to my `success` and your `php` to my cart and the hidden div didnt show and my cart page renders but it `null` data which shouldn't happen. so this is not working.

Comment: I have added action parameters in both request. Have you added that

Comment: yes i did... I will update my question to show u part of my cart code

Comment: i have updated to show my `cart.php` code maybe that will help u in answering my question. Thanks again

Comment: any luck with this? I have try different ways but all of them ends in failure :(

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I tried this and it didn't work... Your code stop items getting added to the cart.